# Click on link only with href

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

**Task:** using selenium in Pyhton, I need to click on link, which consists only href:[image]

**My solution:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from credentials import DRIVER_PATH, LINK
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedgedriver.exe'
LINK = 'https://petstore.octoperf.com/actions/Catalog.action'

class Chart(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        self.fish_selection = "//a[@href='/actions/Catalog.action?viewCategory=&amp;categoryId=FISH']"

    def add_to_chart(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.fish_selection).click()
        time.sleep(3)


def setup():
    return webdriver.Edge(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)


def additiontest():
    driver = setup()
    driver.get(LINK)
    driver.maximize_window()
    welcome_page = Chart(driver)
    welcome_page.add_to_chart()
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    additiontest()
```

**Error:**

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='/actions/Catalog.action?viewCategory=&categoryId=CATS']"}
> (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=107.0.1418.42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `href` value of that element is dynamically changing, so you need to locate that element by fixed part of `href` attribute.
2. You need to wait for element to become clickable.
   This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'FISH')]"))).click()
```

**UPD**
Accordingly to your project structure I think you should use something like this:

```py
class Chart(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        self.fish_selection = "//a[contains(@href,'FISH')]"
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)

    def add_to_chart(self):
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.fish_selection))).click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: running code like this: ` def add_to_chart(self):
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'FISH')]"))).click()` but shows me a problem:

Comment: What problem? Have you added the imports I mentioned and defined the `wait` object as I wrote?

Comment: yes, I added everything, but output..:   target = driver.find_element(*target)  # grab element at locator
AttributeError: 'Chart' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Comment: Maybe it should be `self.driver` instead of `driver` there? In your case

Comment: `class Chart(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
       

    def add_to_chart(self):
        self.driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'FISH')]"))).click()`

Comment: This clearly wrong :) I'll try to edit my answer

Comment: You are welcome! I actually never used such structure, so it's nice I could guess how it should be in your case. Also, actually I'm coding on Java, not Python at all :)